# create option from 2 tabels database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've 2 tables database:

1.table for categories

[image]

2.table for option based on those categories.

[image]

I want to create the group of select based on categories.

[image]

My code:

```html
function config_cat($idVps){
  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from("tbcategory_config as a");
  $this->db->join("tbconfig_option as b", "a.id_category = b.id_category");
  $this->db->where("id_vps",$idVps);
  $hasil = $this->db->get();
  return $hasil;
 }
```

```html
<?php foreach($configcat->result_array() as $row):
         $category =$row['name'];
         $detailCon =$row['detail_config'];
       ?>
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label><?php echo htmlentities($category, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></label>
        <select>
         <option><?php echo htmlentities($detailCon, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></option>
        </select>
       </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I expect the output will show the select option for 
"Upgrade ram"= 1. 1Gb, 2. 2Gb

and

"Upgrade core" = 1 Core

But the actual result is the upgrade ram displayed twice
(based on 3rd picture above)

Comment: @u_mulder i was having trouble by inserting code, but i already fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily the optimal approach, but you may get this solved easily by not using the join clause, and have separate variables with the parent categories and their children.

You don't show your controller, so it's not entirely straight-forward to make a suggestion but try something along these lines:

**In your controller:**
Have two separate variables populated by two separate model calls. One with the content of your  `categories` table and one with the content of your `options` table. It's of paramount importance that both contain the `category_id` field

**In your view:**
You need two nested `foreach` loops. The outermost one looping on the categories. The innermost looping on options.

```
<?php
foreach ($categories as $c)
{ ?
  <select name="<?php echo $c->category_id; ?>">
    <?php
    foreach ($options as $o)
    {
      if ($o->category_id == $c->category_id)
      { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $o->option_id; ?>"><?php echo $o->option_name; ?>
</option>
      <?php 
      } ?>
  </select>
<?php
}
?>
```

change the above to use your own variable names.
By doing this, you'll have one `SELECT` element for each category populated with as many `OPTION` elements as there are options with the same category

Comment: glad to help :)